Is it possible to change a satellite's eccentricity without changing semimajor axis (instantaneous maneuver paradigm)? What else needs to "give"?
I've been wondering whether it's possible to change a satellite's eccentricity without changing its semi-major axis. (I'm assuming instantaneous changes in velocity.) At first I thought that this would be impossible, because changing eccentricity necessarily changes the size of an ellipse when trying to match the before and after ellipse at the point of the maneuver, and changing the size of the ellipse changes the semi-major axis.
But then I realized that I was picturing ellipses with the same orientation. If I change to a different ellipse of the same semi-major axis but different eccentricity than the one I'm currently on, if I rotate the orientation of that second ellipse (change argument of periapsis of the orbit) and don't change the orbital plane, I should be guaranteed to get the two ellipses to intersect at any arbitrary point along the first ellipse, right?
Phrased a different way, if I don't require that argument of periapsis remains fixed (but inclination and RAAN do), I should be able to perform an instantaneous maneuver into an orbit with different eccentricity but same semi-major axis as my current one, correct?
update: I'm looking for a general solution (being able to change eccentricity at any point in the orbit), not just at two points in the orbit.

Any non-instantaneous burn that remains perpendicular to the direction of motion throughout, directed within the plane of the orbit, will change eccentricity without affecting semi-major axis, inclination, or direction of the ascending node.

That is, you just need to change the direction of the velocity without changing its magnitude.  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/676872/123208

@PM2Ring oh that's right, vis-viva Why not write it up? But I wonder if solving for the argument of periapsis that requires the least delta-v for a given new eccentricity is solvable?

@uhoh I'm looking for a general solution (being able to change eccentricity at any point in the orbit), not just at two points in the orbit.

@NeutronStar The comment by PM 2Ring is the general solution. You need to keep the magnitude of the before and after velocities the same.

@notovny Burning perpendicular to the direction of motion does change the semi-major axis length, at least by a bit. Whether finite or impulsive, a burn needs to have at least a slight retrograde component to keep the semi-major axis length unchanged.


Is it possible to change a satellite's eccentricity without changing semimajor axis (instantaneous maneuver paradigm)?

Sure. From the vis-viva equation,
$v^2 = \mu\left(\frac2r-\frac1a\right)$, you simply need to keep kinetic energy the same before and after the instantaneous $\Delta$v to keep the semi-major axis length the same. In other words,
$$\|\vec v + \Delta \vec v\|^2 = v^2\tag{1}$$
It helps to break the instantaneous $\Delta$v into a component parallel (or anti-parallel) to the original velocity vector and a component orthogonal to the original velocity vector:
$$\Delta \vec v = \Delta v_{\|}\hat v + \Delta v_{\perp}\hat v_{\perp}\tag2$$
where

$\hat v$ is the unit vector pointing along the initial velocity vector,
$\Delta v_{\|}$ is the component of the instantaneous $\Delta \vec v$ parallel (or anti-parallel) to the initial velocity vector,
$\hat v_{\perp}$ is a unit vector orthogonal to the initial velocity vector,  and
$\Delta v_{\perp}$ is the component of the instantaneous $\Delta \vec v$ orthogonal to the initial velocity vector.

With this, equation (1) becomes $(v+\Delta v_{\|})^2 + \Delta v_\perp^2 = v^2$ or
$$\Delta v_{\|}^2 + 2 \Delta v_{\|} v + \Delta v_\perp^2 = 0\tag3$$
This is a quadratic equation in $\Delta v_\|$ with solutions
$$\Delta v_\| = -v\pm\sqrt{v^2-\Delta v_\perp^2}\tag4$$
Both solutions have an imaginary component if $\Delta v_\perp > v$. In other words, you can't meet the objective of keeping $a$ the same for ridiculously large burns orthogonal to the original velocity vector. If $\Delta v_\perp = 0$, the two solutions are $\Delta v_\| = 0$ (i.e., no instantaneous $\Delta$v) and $\Delta v_\| = -2v$ (i.e., completely reversing direction). I'll assume you want the smaller burn, so equation (4) becomes
$$\Delta v_\| = -v+\sqrt{v^2-\Delta v_\perp^2}\tag5$$
Note that in the range $0<\Delta v_\perp\le v$, the component along the velocity vector is always negative: The burn will be at least slightly retrograde. (And, as noted above, if $v_\perp > v$, the goal is unacheivable.)
In the case that $\Delta v_\perp \ll v$, equation (5) becomes
$$\Delta v_\| \approx -\frac{\Delta v_\perp^2}{2 v}\tag6$$

What else needs to "give"?

That depends on whether or not the instantaneous $\Delta$v is in-plane. If $\hat v_\perp$ is in plane, the orbital plane won't change, but the argument of periapsis and true anomaly (and hence also the mean and eccentric anomalies) will change. If $\hat v_\perp$ has an out of plane component, the burn will also change the argument of ascending node and the inclination as well.

Note that for any in-plane instantaneous $\Delta$v, the argument of latitude (the angle between the ascending node and the current position, also the sum of the argument of periapsis and the true anomaly) will remain unchanged because the right ascension of ascending node hasn't changed due to the in-plane nature of the maneuver.

+1 for you're godlike mastery of the SE equations feature! (and also a great answer)

Whoever did it, what was the random drive-by downvote for?

@phil1008 When I worked (I'm now retired), my preferred tool for documentation was LaTeX. You can see some of that work here; look at the docs directories in each of the models subdirectories. Every model is documented. My name is on several of those documents, and my influence is on all of them. I led that project for a long time. I also spread the LaTeX religion to other projects.

Thanks for the link @DavidHammen! I didn't know Trick and JEOD was on github.

@OrganicMarble There's one chunk of JEOD that remains subject to ITAR (and should remain subject to ITAR), but I am very happy that NASA deemed the vast majority of JEOD to be NASA open source. It was my baby!

I'm enjoying this derivation, thank you! I have a small question. In 2D a vector's perpendicular normal could arguably point in either direction, they might be referred to as CW and CCW. I'm guessing there's a convention that it's the CCW (i.e. the perpendicular to $\hat{y}$ would be $-\hat{x}$) but I don't know if that's formalized. In your answer this convention would be needed if one wanted to nail down the sign of $\Delta v_\perp$ for planning purposes, since the two signs result in the same eccentricity, but different argument of periapsis. (have I got that right so far?)

(cont.) I think there's a sign convention ambiguity in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/274728/284619 as well but signs always make me dizzy. I attribute my low GPA in college to sign errors (and ok beer et al.) Question: In orbital mechanics in 2D (i.e. here) is there a convention for the perpendicular direction in 2D? In other words, if I suggest a $\Delta v_\perp = -0.1 v$ will most folks interpret that the same way?

@uhoh While it is a two dimensional problem, we do live in a three dimension world that has almost universally adopted the right hand rule. (There are some hangers-on, particularly in computer graphics and aeronautics, that cling to their left hand rule convention. Ignore them.) If one is thrusting mostly perpendicular to the orbital plane, positive $v_\perp$ is in the direction of the right handed angular velocity vector (in the direction of $\vec r \times \vec v$). Otherwise, the authors would be best to establish a sign convention in the paper they wrote.

@DavidHammen Ah, I'm so caught up in the distance between a point and a line problem in Math SE that I forgot there's a central body here. Yes, the choice is obvious here.
